# Slight issue with "in" operator

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that loops indefinitely. I have a list of numbers and I am supposed to ask the user to guess a number on the list. If the user guesses correctly, then the program should tell them so, and likewise if they guess incorrectly. There should also be an option for the user to stop the infinite loop by typing 'q'. Here is the code that I have written for it...

```
X = 0

Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

while X < 1:
    check = input("Guess a number:")
    if check in Y:
        print("You got it right!")
    else:
         if check == "q":
            break
         else:
             if check not in Y:
                 print("Sorry, try again!")


X -= 1
```

The problem I am running into is that, no matter what number is entered in by the user, the program will always output the "Sorry, try again!" string, even if the number is in fact in the list. The loop does successfully stop if the user types in 'q', but I can not get the program to print "You got it right!". I'm sure that I am just missing something small here, but I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out here. Thank you!

Comment: `input()` returns a string; there is no `'1'` string in `Y`.

Comment: Yup, change every 1,2,3,4... to "1","2","3","4"... One more thing, what is the `X` supposed to do?

Comment: Ah yes of course! I should have seen that mistake right there! Thank your both for the help.

Comment: Also with regard to what X is supposed to do, I put it there so that the program would continue its infinite loop, viz. by its value always being less than 5.